# Angular Route Resolver - multiple return types?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular14

I have a component that I've defined for a route which needs 2 different pieces of data when the component initializes.

The route is configured with a resolver:

```
{
    path: "session/:sessionId",
    component: CaptureComponent,
    resolve:{
      session:SessionResolver
    },
    data: {
      title: "Capture Session"
    }
}
```

I have successfully been able to invoke my service and retrieve one of those pieces of data and provide it to my component.

This works beautifully...

```
@Injectable()  
export class SessionResolver implements Resolve<Session> {  
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}  
  
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Session> {  
    const sessionId:number  = route.params['sessionId'];
    return this.sessionService.getSession(sessionId);  
  }  
}
```

However, I want to now modify this resolver to chain an additional service call (to retrieve a Template) that requires data from the session (the templateId) that I just retrieved.  I know I can chain the service calls with a switchMap like this, but this now only returns the Template. I want both the Template ***and*** the Session in my component:

```
@Injectable()  
export class SessionResolver implements Resolve<Template> {  
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}  
  
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Template> {  
    const sessionId:number  = route.params['sessionId'];
    return this.sessionService.getSession(sessionId)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(session => {
          const templateId = session.templateId!;
          return this.sessionService.getTemplate(templateId);
        })
      );  
  }  
}
```

There are 2 pieces to this that I'm unsure how to address.
First, I understand that my resolver will now either have to return a different type; what type can I return to get both pieces of data?

Is there a better way to chain the two service calls so that a custom data type (an array??) can be returned? Should I define a new type that has a session and template attribute and return that type?  If so, how do I take the output of both calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that all I needed to do was ask the question....and then I stumbled into a solution.

I think the only thing left is to define a new custom type to define the attributes of `session` and `template` since right now I've modified it to be of type `any` just to get it working.

This is working for me

```
@Injectable()  
export class SessionResolver implements Resolve<any> {  
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}  
  
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {  
    const sessionId:number  = route.params['sessionId'];
    return this.sessionService.getSession(sessionId)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(session => {
          const templateId = session.templateId!;
          return this.sessionService.getTemplate(templateId)
          .pipe(
            map(
              template => {
                return {
                  'session': session,
                  'template': template
                }
              }
            )
          );
        })
      );  
  }  
}
```